# What does "how to sell your way through life" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I just came across this "how to sell your way through life" (the name of a book written by Napoleon Hill), but I don't really get what it means. Anyone please explains it in details, and please help me understand the expression or kind of sense in "your way through life".

My personal opinion is, it is like "the art of selling yourself" or sort of "the art of selling what you have", or it could go like "the art of life in salesmanship/selling", etc.

I'm quite lost since I can't feel the sense of language in that sentence.

Many thanks!

Comment: "No matter who you are or what you do, you are a salesperson. Every time you speak to someone, share an opinion or explain an idea, you are selling your most powerful asset . . . you!", "we must all be salespeople at key points in our lives." (I think these are back flap texts on the book.)

Comment: Could you rewrite "how to sell your way through life" in another sentence with the same meaning?

Comment: It seems to me that if we told you what it means there would be no point in reading the book.

Comment: I actually want to translate that title into Vietnamese, but It's kind of hard to pick up the appropriate words :(

Answer (score 1):

It helps to be familiar with Napoleon Hill, one of America's self-help gurus, who had a successful career as an author touting a philosophy and way of life to help people be successful in general and as salesmen in particular. One tenet of his teaching is that to sell a product to a customer, you must first sell yourself as a sincere and trustworthy person. Thus the title of his book *How To Sell Your Way Through Life* is a bit of wordplay.  It means 1) the instructions for selling throughout your lifetime and 2) the instructions for selling using a particular way of leading your life.